# Heroku Rails 4-- FileNotFound jquery.ui.all

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running my app on my local server with no issues, and have been pushing to Heroku with no issues until now. I am suddenly seeing this error:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
```

My gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

My `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree ./
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Any chance you can update this post if you solved it? I'm actually running into a very similar problem with Heroku deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line in your Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', github: 'joliss/jquery-ui-rails', branch: 'rails-4.0.2'
```

run

```
bundle update jquery-ui-rails
```

Now you can put in your application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

More informations [here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)

Comment: that throws errors: `couldn't find file 'jquery.ui'`

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: Yes, and restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by renaming the `require` lines in `application.css` and `application.js`.
This issue arises due to changes to the file naming structure in jquery-ui 5.0 ([see this discussion](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/issues/73)).
When using the new versions (>= 5.0.0) of jquery-ui, you need to rename
`//= require jquery.ui.all` to `//= require jquery-ui`
in
`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

and

`*= require jquery.ui.all` to `*= require jquery-ui`
in
`app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still have the error Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all' even after changing the line in gemFile gem 'jquery-ui-rails', github: 'joliss/jquery-ui-rails', branch: 'rails-4.0.2'etc... please I am lost