# Rails 4.1.4: Sprockets::FileNotFound at /admin couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, sprockets

Although, similar question asked, none of the solutions proposed worked.

Everything worked prior to upgrading from Rails 4.0.0 to Rails 4.1.4.  As part of debugging this, I removed the Gemfile.lock and regenerated with "bundle install"

Rails 4.1.4
Ruby 2.0

Sprockets restrained to 2.11.0 due to issues in 2.12.x not working with Rails 4.1.4.  sass-rails restrained to 4.0.2. as part of same issue with restraining sprockets version.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '= 4.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'turbolinks'

group :development do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'erb2haml'

  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
gem 'jbuilder'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.12b5'

gem "sprockets", "2.11.0"
gem 'better_errors', group: :development
gem 'sprockets_better_errors', group: :development
gem 'binding_of_caller', group: :development
gem 'quiet_assets', group: [:development, :test]

# Lots more gems omitted...
```

Excerpt from the Gemfile.lock:

```
jquery-rails (3.1.1)
  railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.0)
  railties (>= 3.2.16)
```

The CoffeeScript that includes the jquery.ui.all line:

```
#= require active_admin/base
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery.ui.all
```

The actual error from "bundle exec rake assets:precompile":

```
03:58:54:website >> bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::VCF
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of VCF was here
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
  (in /Users/mwlang/projects/clients/law/site/website/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee:4)
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:217:in `process_require_directive'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in process_directives'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/mwlang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 7):

After digging in, it turns out the syntax for including jquery-ui-rails in your project's javascript and stylesheet has changed!  The working solution for Rails 4.1.x is:

In your Gemfile, simply include the gem:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

You do not need to specify the source or branch.

Instead of the old way (for everything):

```
#= require jquery.ui.all
```

You now should use:

```
#= require jquery-ui
```

Note the "." becomes a "-"

If you want to include specific components, that, too changes.  Instead of:

```
#= require jquery.ui.sortable
```

Its now:

```
#= require jquery-ui/sortable
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem, and the solution here worked for me: [Heroku Rails 4-- FileNotFound jquery.ui.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703754/heroku-rails-4-filenotfound-jquery-ui-all)

In your gemfile, change the line

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

to

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', github: 'joliss/jquery-ui-rails', branch: 'rails-4.0.2'
```

and then run

```
bundle update
```

Comment: I may need to fork and update gem specs.  When I tried the above, activeadmin complains because its specifying jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0) whereas above branch is recognized as 4.1.0

Comment: I have the same problem and the solution is not working. Even with gem 'jquery-ui-rails', github: 'joliss/jquery-ui-rails', branch: 'rails-4.0.2' and after doing $bundle update it is still Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.0 and I can not run my program... Pleas help

Answer (score 0):

Besides @Michael Lang's answer, I have to do one another thing to make it work:

`//= require jquery-ui` will have to follow `//= require jquery_ujs`

So it will look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```